# How to speed up writing in an entry in .Net Maui using external keyboard?

Tags: .net, maui

I have a .Net maui 7 Android app that I use with an external barcode scanner.

I have an entry that receives the code scanned by the barcode.

```
<Entry x:Name="MyEntry" TextChanged="TextChanged_EH"></Entry>
```

The softkeyboard is disabled for the entry.

I need to scan the following 40 character code : **{"a":"a","x":"HBXjfOQrAL9Z8GF","l":"1"}**

I measure the writing time of the code in the entry as follows :

```
void TextChanged_EH(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        

    if (this.MyEntry.Text == "{")
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
    }

    if (this.MyEntry.Text.Length > 1)
    {
        string myString = this.MyEntry.Text;
        string lastChar = myString.Substring(myString.Length - 1, 1);        

        if (lastChar == "}")
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            this.Label.Text = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The writing of the scanned code takes around 1500 ms.

If I change the entry opacity to :

```
<Entry x:Name="MyEntry" TextChanged="TextChanged_EH" Opacity="0" TextColor="Transparent"></Entry>
```

The writing of the scanned code takes around 800 ms, which is still very long.

Initially the idea of using an external barcode scanner instead of an internal scanning plugin like zxing.net.maui was the speed.

How can I speed up the writing a little more? Ideally, I need to write the same code in an Entry in something around 100ms. I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: I’d guess the TextChanged handler itself is the slowest part of this process

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Jason. Do you have any other idea please ?

Comment: Hi.. How did you disable the keyboard?  Do you have any suggetions on how implement the reading from an external bar code scanner?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most of those scanner can be setup, to send terminating character.

This is usually [LF] or [TAB].

I say, start from here.

Then, you can try to make use of other events (let's say Entry Completed). Or you can try to intercept those keys. (DispatchKeyEvent etc.)